# How to get a not mapped Field with JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm working with JPA to get all mapped fields between database and enities.
I try to get specifically the data of an audited table. And as you know in every audited table we have the same fields like in a normal table but with two others fields (`rev` and `revtype`).

So in the entity I don't have these two fields.

Can i get them without existing as variables with annotation column etc ?

Comment: What's your auditing solution? Envers or something at the database level?

Comment: i use hibernate envers

Comment: I don't think there's a JPA way short of raw SQL. But you can utilize Enver's built-in capabilities described [here](http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/#revisions-of-entity). Maybe that helps achieving your *real* goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Dynamic#DynamicEntity_API
Maybe DynamicEntity can help you to access those fields.